# Entity framework skip one db field value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have very tiny project just to understand 'code first' methodology.

When I create a database using 'code first' and add an object - it works well, all properties of the object are saved in the database.
Then I try to get the saved object. It returns the object, but one property is always null.

Can anybody explain what's wrong with my code, please?

**Entity class**

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }                
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsStoreItem { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }                          
    public string TopBidderId { get; set; }                 
    public Material Material { get; set; }
    public ItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int KrauseNumber { get; set; }                
}
```

**Database entity**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationIdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create() => new ApplicationDbContext();                
    }
}
```

**Generic repo**

```
public class EfGenericRepository<T> : IEfGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    internal readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    internal readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public EfGenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Try to get the entity**

```
public void GetEntity(Guid id)
{
    var context = new Repository();
    var auction = context.ItemRepository.Get().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);                
}
```

**The result is**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Also I must say, that

```
var request = "SELECT TopBidderId FROM Items WHERE Id = '*item_id*'";
var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(request).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
```

works great and it returns absolutely correct value.

Comment: What is TopBidderId data type in the database? It is possible to be GUID, but not string?

Comment: if the data type of `object` in database and in `C#` does not match it will always return that as `null`. Try changing the datatype of `TopBidderId` in your entity class from `String` to `GUID`.

Comment: the data type of `TopBidderId` is `NVARCHAR (MAX)` and it is generated from the entity class where `TopBidderId` is a string value.

Comment: the passing value is just an Id of the object in database. It is not related to the `TopBidderId` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the model I think that Material and ItemStatus are enums otherwise I suggest to mark the properties as virtual (for lazy load).

I'm also not so sure about your repository implementation. Each EfGenericRepository has its own context and I'm not sure that is a good design anyway is not the subject of the question.

The answer:
your model contains a string property named TopBidderId. When you create the database the field type is something similar to 'text' (varchar(max) in recent SQL Servers, text in MySQL, CLOB, and so on). So, inside it, you can write a string. In your case it seems a ToString of a Guid. When you read the content, the string is inserted in the TopBidderId property.
No way that this does not happen, text (or varchar(max)) column can be converted to the string of the TopBidderId of your model.

By the way, I tryed to run your code (starting from a context and not from an IdentityDbContext, adding the two missing enums and the Repository class, default migration) and it works as expected.

So why in your case does not work? I think that your database model is not aligned to your entity model (and the column TopBidderId is not a text or a varchar max). Usually it does not happen but there are some case where it can happen. For example if you disabled model check (check between your entity model and the content of __MigrationHistory table) or you changed the TopBidderId column type after you migrated the database.

Another case is that your entity model is different from the one you posted here (and TopBidderId is a foreign key used by a property TopBidder of type Bidder).

Comment: many thanks for the detailed explanation. You are absolutely right, Material and ItemStatus are enums. I'll try to play with db migrations just to be sure, that the entity is correct. Mark your post as the 'answer'. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for now to detect where actually the issue falls to see the generated select statement executed by the Get . For Entity Framework 6 :

```
public EfGenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    _dbContext.Database.Log = Console.Write; 
}
```

By this you will see the real executed scripts to give you more clear image where exactly is the fall down.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It returns 'SELECT' statement, that contains all the expected fields. So at least the request is correct. I think @vikscool is right and I missed some types convertion.